# sum of array with O(1)

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I have an array of n elements. Smallest element that exists in the array is x and the largest element is x+n. None of the numbers between x to x + n is missing from the array. i need an algorithm to get the sum of all numbers in the array provided that x is already known. The time complexity of this algorithm should be O(1).

Comment: If $x$ and $n$ are integers, there are $n+1$ integers between $x$ and $x+n$ (both included), so the array wouldn't be of size $n$.

Comment: I see a rectangle and a triangle.

Comment: As usual, I am surprised to see how some questions receive very rude answers like "what have you tried ?", "we won't do your homework" and on the other hand, extremely naive questions (not to say "ridiculous") like this receive very welcoming and efficient answering ...

Comment: @Optidad, I'd guess it's not the same people doing the former as those doing the latter.  This probably isn't the right place, but I'd be interested to hear what you think would be the most constructive way to respond to such questions -- perhaps you might open a discussion on [meta] if you have any interest in that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you strictly want $O(1)$, you can just do the math and get that
$$\sum_{i\ \in \ Array}i=\sum_{i=x}^{x+n} i =\sum_{i=1}^{x+n}i\ -\sum_{i=1}^{x-1}i =\frac{(x+n)(x+n+1)}{2}-\frac{(x-1)(x)}{2}$$

I do not see any iterative way to do it as you require the runtime to be $O(1).$

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Djrocks192s answer, we can also calculate it like that:

$$\sum_{i=x}^{x+n} i = \sum_{k=0}^n x+k = nx + \sum_{k=0}^n k = nx + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$